How can I draw text using SVG.js?
I am trying to figure out how to use SVG.js to draw text. In my attempt below, the text is being created and drawn, but only a few dots show up. This must be part of the text being drawn, but it is being clipped. I am not sure why this clipping is happening or how to fix it.
My end goal is to create an SVG with text fitted inside some geometry. To do this, I need to measure the text first so I can compute the geometry dimensions. Therefore, it is important to me to create the SVG object before adding the SVG to a DOM element.
For the code below, what do I need to do so the text show up correctly?


const draw = SVG().size(300, 300);

const text = draw.text("000000000");

text.attr({
  fill: "red",
  stroke: "green",
  "font-family": "Roboto",
  "font-size": 10
});

const bbox = draw.bbox()

console.log( bbox );

draw.addTo("#rectID");
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>

<div id="rectID">
</div>




In your code, where you set the text attributes (text.attr) add a value for the y, for example y:50

As explained by Fuzzyma:
the bbox is calculated by creating a temporarily appended DOM element.
In fact this approach should work flawlessly without any layout shifts.
Your main problem is the off canvas position of the <text> element.
Here's an example generating a horizontally and vertically centered <text> element with a <rect> in the background.
The SVG's markup is returned via svg() method.


const draw = SVG().size(300, 300);
// draw background rect
const rect = draw.rect();
const text = draw.text("000000000");

text.attr({
  fill: "red",
  "font-family": "Roboto",
  "font-size": 50,
  x: "50%",
  y: "50%",
  "text-anchor": "middle",
  "dominant-baseline" : 'middle'
});

// get bounding box
const bbox = draw.bbox();

// adjust rect dimensions according to bbox
rect.attr({
  x: bbox.x,
  y: bbox.y,
  width: bbox.width,
  height: bbox.height,
  fill: "#ccc",
  stroke: "green"
});


// get markup
let markup = draw.svg()
output.value = markup;

function render(){
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup)
}
svg{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

textarea{
  width:100%;
  min-height:10em
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>

<h3>SVG markup</h3>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<p><button onclick="render()">Render SVG</button></p>



As you can see we can also retrieve the SVG markup without rendering the element - albeit the bbox calculation requires some temporary invisible rendering.

You didn't set any position for the text so if will be positioned at 0,0. Text is positioned by its baseline. So most of the text will be outside the svg because it overflows at the top.
Try giving it a position by setting x and y as well.
Also: calling bbox on an element which is not in the Dom yet will yield one of the following:

an error
wrong results
correct results but but an overhead

That's because the browser can only calculate the bounding box for elements that have been rendered. Svg.js tries to get around that by attaching the element to the Dom temporarily but that can yield to wrong results and produces an overhead.
So use add() first and then bbox()

Interesting. So, in order to do what I want, I will need to render an invisible / hidden element, measure, and then create the real one when using SVG? I wish there was a better way. I would go the canvas route, but, while it can measure the text prior to rendering, has terrible rendering of the text itself.

If you could provide a working example with the add so the text will render correctly, it would be appreciated not only by me but also by others coming across this answer.

If you want to measure the text you need to draw it. So yes, in that case, using canvas to measure the text is a possibility to get the measures you need. SVG2 has a feature to put text into a space. However, it is not widely supported by browsers.

What is this SVG2 feature called?

It's just text with a content area it seems: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextLayoutContentArea
